# How to add a Mask Gradient to Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a gradient mask on the right side of a horizontal scrollbar to indicate that the list scrolls horizontally. I've created a gradient-layer as my mask, however the mask moves horizontally with the navigation items when scrolled. I want the mask to stay fixed as the user scrolls through the navigation, but don't want to position it 'fixed' because I  need the mask to be contained within the width and height of the navigation container. But I'm not sure how to achieve this effect. Thanks for the help!

```css
.navigation{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: no-wrap;
   overflow-x: auto;
   background-color: black;
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;

  }
  
  .navigation::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), red 85%);
      width: 15%;
  }

  .item {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

  }
```

```html
<div class = "navigation">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div> 
      <div class="item"></div> 
      <div class="item"></div> 
      <div class="item"></div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:sticky`

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0 20px;
}

.navigation::after {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), red 85%);
  width: 15%;
  margin-left:-15%; /* same a width to not take any space */
  flex-shrink:0; /* this is important to keep the width:15% */
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navigation .item:last-child {
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `position: fixed` while applying the same `height` the `.item` class has?

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), red 85%);
  width: 15%;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```